# apache fop can't get pdf with proper bytes written to

Tags: java, apache-fop, websphere-portal

I am trying to generate a `pdf` download file. I have the following code to generate pdf from `xml` and `xsl-fo`. Can anyone point me what I am missing in my code. When I open the pdf, it says corrupted and if I open that file using `notepad++` all is see is `[B@4bf24bf2` in the file.

```
public void generatePDF(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws IOException {

        PortletContext portletContext = resourceRequest.getPortletSession().getPortletContext();

        URL url = portletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/xsd/xsl-fo.xsl");

        File xsltfile = new File(url.getPath());

        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new File(portletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/xsd/service.xml").getPath()));

        StreamSource transformSource = new StreamSource(xsltfile);

        // Construct FopFactory
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

        // Create ByteArrayOutputStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Setup JAXP using identity transformer
        TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();             
        Transformer xslfoTransformer;

        try {           

            xslfoTransformer = tfactory.newTransformer(transformSource); // identity transformer            

            Fop fop;

            try {

                // Construct fop with desired output format
                fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, outStream);

                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                try {
                    xslfoTransformer.transform(source, res);

                    byte[] pdfBytes = outStream.toByteArray();
                    resourceResponse.setContentLength(pdfBytes.length);
                    resourceResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
                    resourceResponse.addProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=fleetevents.pdf");                 
                    resourceResponse.getWriter().print(pdfBytes);
                    resourceResponse.getWriter().flush();

                } catch (TransformerException exception ) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, exception.getMessage(), exception);

                }

            } catch (FOPException fopException) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, fopException.getMessage(), fopException);

            }
        }  catch(TransformerConfigurationException exception) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, exception.getMessage(), exception);

        } catch(TransformerFactoryConfigurationError  exception) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, exception.getMessage(), exception);

        } 

    }
```

My sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<services>
    <service>
        <serviceId>11111</serviceId>
        <openDate>2012-02-16</openDate>
        <closeDate>2012-02-16</closeDate>
        <orderStatus>Status2</orderStatus>
        <description>INSPECT MACHINE</description>
        <repairCost>$266.76</repairCost>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceId>11111</serviceId>
        <openDate>2012-02-16</openDate>
        <closeDate>2012-02-16</closeDate>
        <orderStatus>Status1</orderStatus>
        <description>INSPECT MACHINE</description>
        <repairCost>$266.76</repairCost>
    </service>
</services>
```

and my sample xsf-fo.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" />
<xsl:template match ="services">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="service">
                <fo:region-body></fo:region-body>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="service">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Service Id</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Open Date</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Close Date</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>                                    
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Order Status</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>                                    
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Description</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
                                text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>Repair Cost</fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <xsl:for-each select="./service">
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="serviceId" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="openDate" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="closeDate" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>                                
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="orderStatus" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="description" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px bold" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="repairCost" /></fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATE**

I think I got it, I need to use `resourceResponse.getPortletOutputStream().write(pdfBytes);
resourceResponse.getPortletOutputStream().flush();` instead of `resourceResponse.getWriter().print(pdfBytes); resourceResponse.getWriter().flush();`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the definitions of getWriter() vs getPortletOutputStream(), it seems getWriter will return a PrintWriter that will only write text to the response.

Whereas PortletOutputStream will write binary data. Since you have quite a few special characters in your xml, I guess it is expected that Printwriter fails to do the job and PortletOutputStream succeeds:
http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/MimeResponse.html